# Ideapad 320-15ISK not booting when inserting RAM upgrade

Tags: boot, laptop, memory, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have purchased a refurbished 8GB, 2400MHz DDR4 RAM stick (M471R1K43BB1-CRC) for my Lenovo Ideapad 320ISK which originally has a 4GB, 2133MHz stick soldered into it.

When I insert the new stick, it does not boot and the screen stays black (no OEM logo or anything). When I power it up, the fan spins for almost 2 seconds and goes off for about 20 seconds and then it starts spinning again for about 5 minutes, at which point it starts spinning at maximum speed (I assume it's max because of the noise that sounds like it normally does when I run an emulator in Intellij).

Because people around me are not using DDR4 laptops, I do not have an alternative laptop to try the new stick in,  and I do not have a different RAM stick to try on this computer so I can check if the slot itself works.

I have tried the following without luck:

- Holding the power button for 30 seconds with charger disconnected.
- Turning fast boot off.
- Resetting my BIOS settings.
- Removing the battery and holding power button for 30 seconds.
- Doing previous step with CMOS battery also disconnected.
- Repeatedly clicking F2, F8, F10, F12 and Esc when turning laptop on.

I can return the RAM stick to the shop I brought it from but I would like help with confirming if it is a compatibility issue, a damage in my RAM slot, a damage to the RAM stick (OOBF) or something else.
Lenovo's [user guide](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad320-15isk_320x-15isk_320-15ikb_320x-15ikb_320-15ikbtouch_ug_en_201704.pdf) lists the 8GB, 2400MHz DDR4 stick as one of the compatible upgrades but I am not sure if this is true for my specific version because they say it should have 8GB of RAM from the factory, but I only got 4GB when I brought it.

PS:  The computer boots normally when I disconnect the new RAM. That is how I have been able to try different BIOS settings.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the refurbished memory is either DOA or there is a hardware compatibility issue. Lenovo likely sells different models of your laptop that DO come with 8 GB.  However, if one of the modules is soldered, that's likely a indication that the laptop only supports 4 GB modules for a total of 8 GB of DDR4.

Comment: I see. I will actually try to get an alternative one of the same size as the soldered one.